# Why won't Jest create a coverage folder?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have `"test": "jest --coverage --color --detectOpenHandles"` set up in my `package.json`. In order to make this work, I have to run `npx jest --coverage` first (to create the `coverage` folder. Otherwise I will get the following error.

I was under the impression that if I run  `jest --coverage` then it would create the `coverage` folder. Is that the wrong assumption?

I have a `TypeScript\Node` application.

The error is:

```
 Failed to write coverage reports:
        ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MY-PATH/coverage/coverage-final.json'
        STACK: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MY-PATH/coverage/coverage-final.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at FileWriter.writeFile (/Users/MY-PATH/node_modules/istanbul-lib-report/lib/file-writer.js:185:41)
    at JsonReport.onStart (/Users/MY-PATH/node_modules/istanbul-reports/lib/json/index.js:17:45)
    at Visitor.value (/Users/MY-PATH/node_modules/istanbul-lib-report/lib/tree.js:38:38)
    at ReportTree.visit (/Users/MY-PATH/node_modules/istanbul-lib-report/lib/tree.js:126:17)
    at JsonReport.execute (/Users/MY-PATH/node_modules/istanbul-lib-report/lib/report-base.js:12:44)
    at /Users/MY-PATH/node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.js:253:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CoverageReporter.onRunComplete (/Users/MY-PATH/node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.js:241:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The contents of `package.json` are:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .ts .",
    "start": "npm run lint && ts-node-dev --respawn --pretty --transpile-only src/server.ts",
    "test": "jest --coverage --color --detectOpenHandles"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^16.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-jwt": "^6.1.0",
    "helmet": "^5.0.1",
    "inversify": "^6.0.1",
    "jwks-rsa": "^2.0.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "winston": "^3.4.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-jwt": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.7",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.1",
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "supertest": "^6.2.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
}
```

`jest.config.ts` looks like:

```
import { Config } from '@jest/types';


export default {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: [
    '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts',
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/lib/',
    '/node_modules/',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'node',
  ],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.ts',
    '!**/*container.(t|j)s',
  ],
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src',
  ],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 80,
    },
  },
} as Config.InitialOptions;
```

Comment: I just ran into this, and it was because the user running the test didn't have sufficient permissions to write to the filesystem

Comment: can happen as well, when there are no files for coverage are being picked up. Thus it's better to ensure first with a minimal example that the general setup is ok, before digging into the folder issue.